# Continuous depedence of the spectrum on elements

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Suppose $a_n \to a$ in a unital C*-algebra $A$. If $\lambda_n \in \sigma(a_n)$ and $\lambda_n \to \lambda$, then $\lambda \in \sigma(a)$. Does the converse hold?

So if $\lambda \in \sigma(a)$, does there exist a sequence $\lambda_n \in \sigma(a_n)$ with $\lambda_n \to \lambda$?

It is true if $A$ is commutative or $A = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, but in the general case I don't see a proof. It feels like such a basic thing should be known, but I cannot find it anywhere - and my StackExchange question was unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not true.

The sequence of operators $U_k$ on $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ defined by $U_ke_n = e_{n-1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus 0$ and $U_ke_0=k^{-1}e_{-1}$ converges to $U_\infty$ defined by $U_\infty e_n = e_{n-1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus 0$ and 
$U_\infty e_0=0$.

The spectrum of $U_\infty$ is the closed unit disc and the spectrum of $U_k$ is just the boundary of the unit disc for all $k$.

Comment: So it does not hold in general. Is there a counterexample if all the $a_n$ are normal?

Comment: @Martin Wortel: You can find some information in [J.B. Conway and Morrel. Operators that are points of spectral continuity. Integral Equations operator Theory 2 (1979), 174-198]. Introduction: A result of Newburgh implies that if each $A_k$ is a normal operator and $A_k$ converges to $A$ then $\sigma(A_k)$ converges to $\sigma(A)$ with respect to the Hausdorff metric for compact sets. See 3.1 Theorem for a characterization of the operators that are points of spectral continuity.